# java- NoClassDefFoundERROR: LogManager

Tags: java, logging

I am trying to program a simple log4j2 logging message.

This is how the code looks like:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class Main {

   private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String message = "Hello there!";
        System.out.println(message);
        logger.info(message);

    }
}
```

And my external libraries importing the API:

[image: Screenshot]

When I run the program, it throws an :

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager
```

I have already imported the relevant jar files but do not understand why do I still get this error.

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: Some version conflict ( https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.6.1/manual/migration.html ): "The main package in version 1 is `org.apache.log4j`, in version 2 it is `org.apache.logging.log4j`"

Comment: so should i be using which version?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of the actual library `log4j-api-2.11.1.jar` you included only the API bridge `log4j-1.2-api-2.11.1.jar` in the classpath. It translates your API 1 calls to API 2 calls. But the actual library handling the calls is missing.

Add the actual library to classpath and either remove the bridge and rewrite the API calls (recommended) or keep the bridge and stay with API 1 calls.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use log4j2, but instead you are using log4j as import.
To make your project work you have to do 2 things:

1. As @Huan Zhang suggested, add imports

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```

2. Remove all jars starting with log4j-1.x. (like first jar in your screenshot). I made the same mistake, because when I downloaded the log4j dependency package, I didnt know which files I need, so added all of them. But by doing so for whatever reason now log4j 1 got activated instead of log4j 2.

Answer (score -2):

Try import LogManager and Logger with the following code:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
```